# Deque last element insert.

Tags: java, algorithm, deque

Datastructure Degue.

Method to insert value in front:

Work fine.

```
 public void insertLeft(Item item) {       
       if (size == deque.length){
          resize(2 * deque.length);
      }
      deque[start] = item;
      start++;
      size++;
}
```

Method to insert value in tail - overwrite last element because of this line `//end = deque.length - 1;`

```
public void insertRight(Item item) {
    if (size == deque.length){
        resize(2 * deque.length);
    }
    end = deque.length - 1;
    deque[end++] = item;
    end %= deque.length;
    size++;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the array is size 10 and currently has 3 values:

```
_ _ _ 1 2 3 _ _ _ _
      ^     ^
  start     end
```

As you can see, your `insertLeft` method is wrong:

- It would replace an existing value
- It moves the index in the wrong direction
- It doesn't handle wrap-around

And your `insertRight` method is wrong:

- It throws away the `end` value

Re-think what you're doing, e.g. does the `resize()` method handle the condition where the array has wrapped?

Example:

```
3 4 5 _ _ _ _ _ 1 2
      ^         ^
    end         start
```

If you call `insertRight()` 5 times, you get:

```
3 4 5 X X X X X 1 2
                ^
                start
                end
```

A 6th call to `insertRight()` would trigger `resize()`, but would it correct handle it? E.g. resulting in:

```
3 4 5 X X X X X Y _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 1 2
                  ^                 ^
                  end               start
```

Answer (score 0):

`deque.length - 1` is returning the index of the last variable. You have to get one past that:

`deque[++end] = item;`

Comment: and get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` Because it will be link on not existing element;

Comment: Seems like a resizing issue. What do you mean not linking on an existing element

Comment: deque.length - 1 is the last element in deque. This element deque[++end] is not exist.

Comment: Isn't that what resize is doing? Are you trying to replace the last element or append an element?

Comment: try to not replace last element, and append next element on the previous index